# SQLite and SQLiteCursorLoader Library

Tags: android, sqlite, android-cursoradapter, android-cursor, android-cursorloader

I have used Android's `SQLite` before but I have always managed rows of data manually, so I never used classes like `SimpleCursorAdapter`. I want to start using them now, but I need a little help in the code implementation, since it says I HAVE to use a `CursorLoader`. I decided I'm using `SQLiteCursorLoader` library.

Here are the details:

I have a table called `students` in the SQLite database. Also, `Student` model class and `StudentManager` controller class. Calling `StudentManager#getAll()` returns a `Cursor` containing all the students.

Let's move to the `Fragment`. I am **not** using `ListFragment` for versatility. Anyway, until now I have the following inside `onCreate`:

```
studentCursor = studentManager.getAll();
String[] from = new String[] { EventManager.COLUMN_TITLE };
String[] to = new String[] { R.id.title };
cursorAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.row_events, eventCursor, from, to, 0);
```

Then, I'd have an `AsyncTask` subclass which will retrieve data from a RESTful API.

```
@Override
public void doInBackground() {
    // code to get an array of students

    for(Student student in students) {
        studentManager.save(student);
    }
}
```

The question would be, in which part would I use the `SQLiteCursorLoader` and what for

**EDIT**: The question is more likely to be something like this: I am already implementing my own `AsyncTask` operation cause I'm retrieving and managing all the data from a server. So, if I am already managing the data in a secondary thread thanks to `doInBackground`, do I need still `SQLiteCursorLoader` for any operation?

Comment: I do not know what "it" is, but you do not have to use a `Loader` with `SimpleCursorAdapter`. If you are looking to learn what the `Loader` framework is about, that is covered in [the documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/loaders.html).

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer, I edited my post for a more accurate question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> So, if I am already managing the data in a secondary thread thanks to doInBackground, do I need still SQLiteCursorLoader for any operation?

Probably not. The point of a `Loader` is to load data asynchronously. If you are doing that yourself, a `Loader` will not somehow make it *more* asynchronous. :-)

Just remember that if you change your data, you will need to run a new `AsyncTask` to update your UI to reflect the changed data, such as by retrieving a fresh `Cursor`. A `CursorLoader` does that automatically; a `SQLiteCursorLoader` only does that "automatically" if you run the database operation through the loader itself.

Comment: Ok this is a pretty complete answer, I have been looking for this information for about 3 hours now. Thanks a lot. I'm mostly doing SELECT operations from my application, and since they have to be validated server-side, I'm always gonna work inside a secondary thread.  Edit: Also, +1 for the "If you are doing that yourself, a Loader will not somehow make it more asynchronous. :-)" xD

Comment: The part where you say I need to retrieve a fresh cursor you mean setting a new cursor to the adapter?

Comment: @ChristopherFrancisco: Yes, or whatever other things you are doing with the `Cursor`.

Comment: I see. Quick question, is SQLiteCursorLoader a replacement for SQLiteDatabase?

Comment: @ChristopherFrancisco: No, `SQLiteCursorLoader` *uses* a `SQLiteDatabase` that you supply it.

Answer (score 1):

The purpose of using the `CursorLoader` interface is so that you're not performing database operations on the main application thread (potentially affecting your application's responsiveness). The `SQLiteCursorLoader` provides an interface that's similar to the old `SimpleCursorAdapter`, but will perform database operations in an `AsyncTask`.

The GitHup page for `SQLiteCursorAdapter` has more information/background: https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-loaderex

Comment: I editted my post for a more accurate question, thanks for the quick reply btw

Comment: What happens to this data retrieved from the server? I imagine it makes its way into your SQLite database. If so, and you want to load this data for display, then that part also needs to happen in an `AsyncTask`, which is where `SQLiteCursorLoader` comes in.

Comment: You're right. Until now I'm doing the saving to database inside doInBackground, could I get an example please?

Comment: Just check out the github page there are plenty of examples including a sample Eclipse project.